# How can I copy table td using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have a table i need if i click on any cell copy it to clipboard using `jquery` or `javascript` i tried to put the same id to every td and if i click to this element copy it but i cant do it

```
<table id="myTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="table100-head">
                                <th class="column1">id</th>
                                <th class="column2">user</th>
                                <th class="column3">pass</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                <td id="copyte" class="column1">1</td>
                                <td id="copyte" class="column2">admino</td>
                                <td id="copyte" class="column3">123456</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td id="copyte" class="column1">2</td>
                                <td id="copyte" class="column2">aa</td>
                                <td id="copyte" class="column3">123456</td>
                                </tr> 
                                <tr>
                                <td id="copyte" class="column1">3</td>
                                <td id="copyte" class="column2">bb</td>
                                <td id="copyte" class="column3">123456</td>
                                </tr>                               
                        </tbody>
</table>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^="copyte"]').click(function(e) {  
      alert(1);
    });
});
```

Is there a better idea or solution?

Comment: Putting the same `id` on every element is not only invalid but achieves nothing. You can simply use `$('td').click()` and use `$(this).text()` inside the handler to get the text.

Comment: Id NEEDS to be unique. You CAN NOT have two elements with same id...

Comment: Once you've fixed the id issue, then you can easily read the `text()` of the clicked cell, and use this technique to copy it to the clipboard on the device: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `class` selector for your `td` to copy their text on click. `Id's` must be unique for each element on the page.

To get all the elements you can use `$.each` method and then apply an `event listener` on them a `click` function and and you can use `$(this).text()` to get the clicked `td's` text only.

We need to create an `empty` input so that we can use that input that copying our text and once the text is copied you we will remove `input` from the page.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.copyte').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).click(function() {
      var clickedTdText = $(this).text() //get the clicked text
      var temp = $("<input>"); //create temp  input
      $("body").append(temp); //append temp input
      temp.val(clickedTdText).select(); //select text
      document.execCommand("copy");
      temp.remove(); //remove temp inout
      alert('Copied Successfully: ' + clickedTdText)
    })
  })
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table100-head">
      <th class="column1">id</th>
      <th class="column2">user</th>
      <th class="column3">pass</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="column1 copyte">1</td>
      <td class="column2 copyte">admino</td>
      <td class="column3 copyte">123456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="column1 copyte">2</td>
      <td class="column2 copyte">aa</td>
      <td class="column3 copyte">1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="column1 copyte">3</td>
      <td class="column2 copyte">bb</td>
      <td class="column3 copyte">123</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, as per your title you need to copy the content of the table on click, okay try my below snippet it's working a charm,

**note**:

you can't use the same id for more than 1 element in HTML so I changed your `id="copyte"` to the `class =copyte`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.copyte').click(function(e) {
      var $temp = $("<input>");
      $("body").append($temp);
      $temp.val($(this).html()).select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      $temp.remove();
      alert($(this).html() + ' copied')
    });
});
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table100-head">
      <th class="column1">id</th>
      <th class="column2">user</th>
      <th class="column3">pass</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="column1">1</td>
      <td class="column2 copyte">admino</td>
      <td class="column3 copyte">123456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="column1 copyte">2</td>
      <td class="column2 copyte">aa</td>
      <td class="column3 copyte">123456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="column1 copyte">3</td>
      <td class="column2 copyte">bb</td>
      <td class="column3 copyte">123456</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: exact same answer and same structure wao :)

Comment: check the method of calling the function ;-), you had used each,  I just added a click event